# Understanding variable capture by closures in Javascript/Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, closures

Is there a definite source on variable capture in Javascript besides the standard (it's a pain to read the standard)?

In the following code `i` is copied by value:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    (function (i)
    {
        process.nextTick(function ()
        {
            console.log(i)
        })
    }) (i)
}
```

So it prints 1..10. `process.nextTick` is an analog of `setTimeout(f,0)` in node.

But in the next code i doesn't seem to be copied:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
        var j = i
        process.nextTick(function ()
        {
            console.log(j)
        })
}
```

It prints 9 10 times. Why? I'm more interested in a reference/general article than in explaining this concrete case of capture.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I don't have a handy reference.  But the bottom line is: In the first, you're explicitly passing in `i` to an anonymous function, which creates a new scope.  You are not creating a new scope for either `i` or `j` in the second.  Also, JavaScript always captures variables, not values.  So you would be able to modify i too.

The JavaScript `var` keyword has function scope, not block scope.  So a for loop does not create a scope.

As a note, the non-standard [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) keyword has local scope.

Comment: @nponeccop, JavaScript has function scope.

Comment: I'm hitting my head against the table. Didn't know that, assumed it's C++ or Perl or Haskell :) Fascinating

Comment: Just if someone ever needs that, node supports `let` with `--harmony_block_scoping` command line arg

Comment: ` JavaScript always captures variables, not values. ` where does this come from?

Comment: As a side note, the `let` keyword has been standardized since. As for "variables, not values" most languages capture variables. But e.g. modern C++ can capture by value.

Comment: @nponeccop I believe java captures values, not variables.

Comment: damn there was a time `let` was non-standard.

Answer (score 9):

In JavaScript, functions *enclose* variables which were defined in a scope outside of their own in such a way that they have a "living" reference to the variable, not a snapshot of its value at any particular time.

So in your second example, you create ten anonymous functions (in `process.nextTick(function(){...})`) which *enclose* the variable `j` (and `i`, which always have the same value when the anonymous function is created).  Each of these functions use the value of `j` at a time *after* the outer for-loop has run entirely, so `j=i=10` at the time that each of the functions is called.  That is, first your for-loop runs entirely, then your anonymous functions run and use the value of `j`, which is already set to 10!

In your first example, the situation is a little different.  By wrapping the call to `process.nextTick(...)` in it's own anonymous function and by binding the value of `i` into a function-local scope by calling the wrapper function (and incidentally *shadowing* the old variable `i` into the function parameter `i`), you capture the value of the variable `i` at that *moment*, instead of retaining the *enclosed reference* to `i` whose value changes in the enclosure of the inner anonymous functions.

To clarify your first example somewhat, try changing the anonymous wrapper function to use an argument named `x` (`(function (x) { process.nextTick(...); })(i)`).  Here we clearly see that `x` takes the value in `i` at the moment the anonymous function is called so it will get each of the values in the for-loop (1..10).

Comment: What's the best-practice solution to capture the value instead of retaining the enclosed reference?

Comment: @JarrodSmith declare a `const value = ...` just prior to your closure and you'll only capture the value as it was.

Answer (score 5):

It is copied (or assigned) in your second example, it's just that there's only one copy of variable `j` and it will have the value that it last had in it which will be 9 (the last rev of your for loop).  You need a new function closure to create a new copy of a variable for each rev of the `for` loop.  Your second example just has one variable that is common to all revs of your  `for` loop, thus it can only have one value.

I don't know of any definitive writeup on this topic.

Variables in javascript are scoped to the function level.  There is no block scoping in javascript.  As such, if you want a new version of a variable for each rev of the for loop, you have to use a new function (creating a function closure) to capture that new value each time through the `for` loop.  Without the function closure, the one variable will just have one value that will be common to all users of that variable.

When you declare a variable such as your `var j = i;` at some location other than the beginning of the function, javascript hoists the definition to the top of the function and your code becomes equivalent to this:

```
var j;
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
        j = i;
        process.nextTick(function ()
        {
            console.log(j)
        })
}
```

This is called `variable hoisting` and is a term you could Google if you want to read more about it.  But, the point is that there is only function scope so a variable declared anywhere in a function is actually declared once at the top of the function and then assigned to anywhere in the function.

Comment: Updated my answer with more detail on your situation.

Answer (score 1):

for the first example, `i`'s are not same.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    (function (i) { //  capture i as the new i in this closure scope.
        process.nextTick(function () {
            console.log(i) //  reference new i (captured).
        })
    })(i)
}
```

[Closures/Value capture - Rosetta Code](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Closures/Value_capture)