# ExtJS column renderer

Tags: javascript, extjs4, renderer

My Problem is the renderer function of a column in a GridPanel in ExtJS 4. The record of the renderer should load an element of my list from my store, and it does; but it always loads the same element of the list.

Here are relevant snippets of my code.

First my Store:

```
var nStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    storeId: 'people',
    fields: ['team', 'name', 'liste', 'sums'],
    data: [{
        team: 'TestTeam', name: 'TestPerson',
        liste: ['F', 'F', 'F', 'S', 'N', 'F', 'S',
            'S', 'S', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'S', 'A', 'N',
            'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', '', '', 'N', 'N',
            'N', 'S', 'S', 'N', 'S', 'F', 'N', 'N'],
        sums: [[7, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [3, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
    }]
});
```

Then my column array where the renderer is:

```
var counter = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < Object.kws.length; i++) {
    var DayOfMonth = [];
    var DayOfWeek = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < Object.kws[i].kwDays.length; j++) {
        var c = counter;
        DayOfMonth[j] = {
            text: '<span style="font-size: 87%;">' 
                    + Object.kws[i].kwDays[j].day 
                    + '.<br>' 
                    + Object.kws[i].kwDays[j].dayOfWeek
                    + '.</span>', sortable: false,
            draggable: false, menuDisabled: true,
            resizable: false, width: 40, align: 'center',
            renderer: function (value, meta, record) {
                return record.data.liste[c];

            }
        };
        counter++;
    }
}
```

The code is adapted and abridged.

Here is a [picture of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUgoE.jpg):

[image: The Result]

Normally the cells in the grid should show the counted element of the list in my Store.

Can anyone help me understand what I am doing wrong?

Comment: sorry about the bad formatting

Comment: I'm not clear on how you are configuring your GridPanel here, but obviously c is not what you expect it to be. Possibly you could manage 'c' in another way? - you seem to have only one record in your store, so maybe you could infer 'c' from the other values passed to renderer? For example, the fourth argument passed is 'rowIndex' and the fifth argument is 'colIndex' so something like c = (rowIndex) * 7 + colIndex + 1; (assuming you always have seven days in a row)?

Comment: there are more records in my Store depends on the count of Employees. There are more then 7 Days in one row. It depends by the lenght of a Month.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is:

> In JavaScript, functions enclose variables which were defined in a scope outside of their own in such a way that they have a "living" reference to the variable, not a snapshot of its value at any particular time.

[Understanding variable capture by closures in Javascript/Node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10095404/understanding-variable-capture-by-closures-in-javascript-node) and
[How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Since 'c' or 'counter' is fully incremented before the method that uses 'c' is invoked, the value of 'c' is always the highest value achieved in the for loop. To solve the issue you need to capture the value of 'c' at the point in time your renderer function is created. This code illustrates the issue and how to capture the value to achieve your desired effect:

```
var counter = 0;
var dayOfMonths = [];
var dayOfMonthCaptured = [];
 for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  var c = counter;
  console.log(c);
  dayOfMonths.push(function () { 
    var index = c;
    //since counter is incremented fully before this method is called, you get the last value
    console.log(index); 
  });
  //here we pass the current value of c to a new function and capture its current value
  dayOfMonthCaptured.push((function (index) {
      return function () { 
        console.log(index); 
      };
   })(c));
  counter++;
}
//this won’t work
for (day in dayOfMonths) {
  dayOfMonths[day]();
}
console.log("—————————");
for (day in dayOfMonthCaptured) {
  dayOfMonthCaptured[day]();
}
```

Comment: That's correct.  Another way to say it is that c is being shared by all the different renderers.