# NodeJS and parallel flow

Tags: node.js

I'm new with NodeJS. An issue makes me confused is parallel flow. I read an example show this snippet as a technique for controlling parallel flow:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var fileDir = './files';

fs.readdir(filesDir, function (err, files) {
    if (err) throw err;

    for (var index in files) {
        var task = (function (file) {
            return function () {
                fs.readFile(file, function (err, text) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    doSomething();
                });
            }
        })(filesDir + '/' + files[index]);

        tasks.push(task);
    }

    for (var index in tasks) {
        tasks[index]();
    }
});
```

This code work like a charm, but when I replace it with

```
    for (var index in files) {
        var task = function () {
            console.log(files[index]);
            fs.readFile(filesDir + '/' + files[index], function (err, text)   {
                if (err) throw err;
                doSomething();
            });
        };

        tasks.push(task);
    }

    for (var index in tasks) {
        tasks[index]();
    }
```

It doesn't work as I expected, because the **files[index]** in loop is always the last file in directory. Could you please explain me what the real flow is?

Answer (score 1):

In short, the function you created have reference for the index variable(not it's value), so when it's executed, the index value is the last file in directory in your case.

Some links: [Understanding variable capture by closures in Javascript/Node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10095404/understanding-variable-capture-by-closures-in-javascript-node)

Comment: Your link is very useful. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Its because index reference will be to its last file. Node js is asynchronous that it ll not wait till read file operation is completed. It ll increment index value.

```
for (var index in files) {
    var task = function () {
        console.log(files[index]);
        fs.readFile(filesDir + '/' + files[index], function (err, text)   {
            if (err) throw err;
            doSomething();
        });
    };

    tasks.push(task);
}
```

Since first code uses closures and it passes the current indexed file to a function. It ll take the current indexed file and returns a function with the file as input.

Now that returned function will execute in parallel.